# Call onBlur event only when tab key is pressed

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a textbox on which I want to execute onBlur event only when tab key is pressed to remove focus from textbox.

How can I do this through javascript?

Any help is appreciated..

Answer (score 4):

In browsers, pressing the tab key when a control has focus will move it to the next element in the tab order, causing the current element to lose focus and dispatch a blur event.

Therefore you can just test for the pressing of the tab key and call your function based on that, e.g.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function showKey(e) {
  return e.which || e.keyCode;
}

</script>
<form>
  <input type="text" onkeydown="this.form.msg.value = showKey(event);">
  <input type="text" name="msg">
</form>
```

The above shows that the tab key has a value of 9, so you can do:

```
if ((e.which || e.keyCode) == 9) {
  // tab key was pressed, do stuff
}
```

Note that while most browsers support e.which, others e.keyCode.

#### Edit

Based on your comment, the following shows that when the control loses focus, the value of the hidden field has been set:

```
  <input type="text" onkeydown="this.form.msg.value = showKey(event);
  (event);" onblur="alert(this.form.msg.value);">
```

Comment: I have already tried this.. i m setting the keycode to a hiddenfield and thn retrieve the value of tht hiddenfield in code behind.. but on tab key press while focus is on textbox, the hiddenfield value is blank.

Answer (score 1):

```
`enter code here`

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#theDiv input").bind("blur", function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                var isOut = true;
                $("#theDiv input").each(function () {
                    if (this == document.activeElement) isOut = false;
                });
                if (isOut) {
                    // YOUR CODE HERE
                    alert("I am called");
                }
            }, 10);
        });
    });
</script>
<!-- ... -->
<div id="theDiv">
    <input type="text" value="Inside DIV 1" />
    <input type="text" value="Inside DIV 2" />
    <input type="text" value="Inside DIV 3" />
</div>
<input type="text" value="Outside DIV" />
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function callfunc() {
 alert("Hello");
}

</script>


<form>
  <input type="text" onblur="callfunc();">
</form>
```

Comment: you should read the question exactly. the blur event could also be fired when clicking into another input element.